# My 2005 Mitsubishi Outlander is spitting coolant out the overflow tank at the top and causing my car to overheat

Tags: overheating, mitsubishi, coolant-leak

My 2005 Mitsubishi Outlander is spitting out coolant at the top of my overflow tank don’t know why. replaced the water pump because it had a slight leak checked the thermostat it worked just fine. Did not over fill the coolant and purged it until all the bubbles come out but I have no idea why it’s leaking. Anything helps thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

Overheating and spitting coolant are both possible symptoms of a blown head gasket. Do a cylinder leakdown test to either confirm or eliminate the head gasket as the source of the problem.